# keyboard shortcut for pasting in gnu screen

Tags: gnu-screen

how can I paste the text in my system clipboard using screen over an ssh connection with Putty?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> should do it. Otherwise, right click and hit "Paste".

Answer (score 2):

" Right click" automatically pastes in the clipboard in Putty.